# Getting Exception NoClassDefFoundError in Appium

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium, noclassdeffounderror

Getting Exception **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/HasTouchScreen** in Appium while clicking on an Element. I have used **three locators(text,id,partialLinkText)** in my code same Task but still getting the Same Exception Every time. PFB the App DOM Screenshot, code,Exception,jarfile version

1. selenium-android-driver.jar
2. java-client-4.1.2 (1).jar
3. selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar

I am trying to click on Text "Sign in Or" so i can automate the signin Module. But I got stuck in First Step only :(

[image]

**Code**

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.android.AndroidDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class searsLogin {
    AndroidDriver driver;
  @BeforeTest
  public void setup() throws MalformedURLException {
      DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "ccdcb242");
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "ANDROID");
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "5.1.1");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
          capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.sears.android");
            capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.sears.activity.MenuDrawerActivity");
             driver = (AndroidDriver) new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
           driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
    @Test
  void execution()
  {
        // driver.findElementByName("Sign in or").click();/// contains method
 // boolean res = driver.findElement(By.name("Sign in or")).isDisplayed();  
//boolean res =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Sign in or')]")).isDisplayed();
  driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Sign in or")).click(); 
     }
   @AfterTest
  public void end()
  {
      driver.quit();
  }  }
```

**Exception Message**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/HasTouchScreen
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: This is wrong  driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Sign in or")).click();,
check this out,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bT3tqaLNn-Y

Comment: @Manidroid it didn't work manidroid

Comment: selenium-android-driver.jar ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using WEB locator for mobile.
The correct XPath for this action would be following:

```
By.xpath("//*[@text='Sign in or']")
```

Answer (score -1):

In Appium v1.5.3 - Android,For Clicking on Locator "Name" try with :

driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().text(\"Locator name\")").click();

For mentioned screenshot
 : driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().text(\"Sign in or\")").click();

Comment: You have not answered the question, just posted some random lines of code. Explain what it is that you are doing differently so that the person asking the question knows what is going on.